# Does "the proceeding" mean "the following"?

Tags: meaning

> The proceeding file naming should then follow the rules detailed
>   below.

I read it from a manual on how to name a file, and does "proceeding" mean "following" here?

Comment: I would think so but that's non-standard. Hard to think of another meaning without more background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a mistake for *preceding*, which means the reverse of "following" - the one coming just before.

"The proceeding file naming" doesn't make any sense at all to me.

I take the intended meaning to be "The name for the file we have just mentioned should follow the rules ... "